# Would you be interested in a “Topic of the Week” contest?

Tags: discussion

We did something similar on [Philosophy](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291/its-descartes-week), where we designate one philosopher each week, and each person who asks a question relating to that philosopher is eligible to win a prize. It's gotten a positive response so far, and we could easily adapt the model to photography topics. Everyone who asks a question about a given week's photo topic is entered into a drawing to win prizes.

Some example topics are bags/cases for carrying your photography gear, various options for displaying/presenting photos, flashes and lighting, macro photography techniques, nature photography techniques, etc. A great way to start would be to think about topics that are popular during the holidays and begin with those.

What do you think? If you have suggestions for weekly topics, please leave them here as well!

**Edit: See below for my suggestion for the first week's topic; let me know if there are any concerns or alternative suggestions.**

[Note: This contest would run on the main site, and the goal is to generate questions and answers about topics that we don't cover as much as we'd like, or topics that we think will be very popular in the coming weeks or months. We're working on a separate contest that would take place on meta and encourage our community's creative side, so stay tuned for that later.]

Answer (score 4):

How do you guys feel about using "macro" as the first topic for this? It seems like we have a decent number of people who know their way around macro lenses and techniques, and beginners often have questions about how to achieve a good macro shot. I'd like to start next week (beginning Monday morning), so if you have any other ideas, let us know (in a separate answer)!

Comment: Sounds as good a place to start as any - I'm not sure we have many real macro masters though.  We can definitely generate some questions, hopefully we get good answers.

Comment: So, uh, [it's not working](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macro?sort=newest&pagesize=50). There's 7 from @rfusca (already a big site contributor, of course), and that's more than half of 'em. And there's been none in the last two days. I think there's gotta be more macro questions out there; we need more publicity, maybe.

Comment: @mattdm - Jin offered to make adverts to go on the community banner thing...should see if he'll do a generic theme one that links to a meta post about whatever current or next theme week is going on?

Comment: @rfusca — How often will Jin make us new ads? How often are we going to have Topics of the Week?

Comment: @mattdm - don't know, that's why I was suggesting a generic 'Topic of the Week' add that always points to the same Meta post and we can update the meta post to update the content.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. I was noticing this on the other sites and thinking the same thing. It'd be double-plus good if we could tie them to the photo contest theme that week — or, I guess, the *previous* week so we'd have the appropriate photo for the header.

Comment: Oooh, tying them to the photo contest theme is a neat idea. Definitely worth a shot!